# Is the GPIO configuration changed for Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: gpio

When I wanted to start working with *Raspberry Pi Zero*, I presumed the GPIO configuration is the same as for *A+*, *B+* and *Pi2* and I wanted to confirm it is true. However, I couldn't find an **official** confirmation.

Is the GPIO BCM layout for *Raspberry Pi Zero* like below ([source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio-plus-and-raspi2)) ?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the pinouts match with the A+, B+ and Pi2. One change that you will notice immediately is that the Pi Zero does not have any headers preinstalled, you will need to add these yourself and depending on where you get your Pi purchase them yourself. This does give you several other options, beyond the standard male headers,  including soldering connections directly to the board, using flamle headers and using a set of right angle headers to permit a vertical mounting similar to a PCI card in your computer.

[image: with female headers]

[image: with right angle headers]

More info on the differences between the zero and earlier Pi's can be found in this post introducing the [PI zero](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-zero).

Answer (score 2):

All the current Pi models with the 40 pin expansion header share the same pinout.

```
GPIO       pin  pin    GPIO
3V3         1    2      5V
2 (SDA)     3    4      5V
3 (SCL)     5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
27         13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

If the GPIO column has a V it indicates the pin is connected to the power rail and is not a GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

No, they haven't changed at all. The pic you attached is valid for the Zero.